How can I selectively relax contraints in Pyomo?
I am currently trying my hand at implementing a type of benders decomposition I need for a set of MINLP problems. The solver uses a NLP primal model and a MILP master. The primal is in the form below with some constraints being a function of x and some being a function of both x and y, where y is a parameter fixed by the master solution.
Description primal model
I have used code of this form to implement the primal.
primal = ConcreteModel()


primal.x = Var() #cont. var determined in primal
primal.y = Param() #fixed binary variable determined in Master problem

def equality_constraint_rule(model):
    return model.x == 0
primal.equality_constraint = Constraint(rule=equality_constraint_rule)

def inequality_constraint_rule(model):
    return model.x + model.y <= 0 
model.inequality_constraint = Constraint(rule=inequality_constraint_rule)


I am working with a case in which many of the y parameters suggested by the Master problem are likely to lead to an infeasible primal. The literature around the algorithm suggests that a good solution is to run a feasibility restoration by relaxing contraints, and to use the multipliers thus obtained to add a feasibility cut as an additional constraint in the master problem (see
Feasibility cut constraint in Master )
I have tried to do this using the a built-in solver restoration phase. IPOPT (which I am using for the primal) automatically starts a restoration like that when the problem is infeasible. However, it relaxes all constraints and for my model always returns a restoration point where the inequalities are enforced, yet the equalities are not, making the result useless for the master solver.
Ideally, I would like the opposite case, i.e. for a restoration which relaxes only the inequalities, yet strictly enforces the equalities. Is there any way this can be achieved?
I have thought about simply deactivating the inequalities, yet I do not think that will provide me with the multipliers I would like.
